# Game crashes half the times I try to run it

Tags: games

Thanks to the help of the Community I was able to install Descent:Freespace using Wine.

Now when I try to run it, most of the times the screen turns black and the system becomes completely unresponsive. Sometimes the game loads, but the top and bottom of the game screen are covered by the Ubuntu desktop menu bars, and I can't move the mouse to the edges of the screen.

How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: To be honest.. what would you expected, Wine isn't perfect, have you tried any fix for the game at winehq?

Comment: @ralf - try running winecfg - emulate a desktop - does running the game in a window work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, Wine project has an "application compatibility database" and it appears that Descent:Freespace has quite good ratings there - Gold or Platinum, which means your chances of making it work are not that bad: http://www.winehq.org/search?cx=partner-pub-0971840239976722%3Aw9sqbcsxtyf&cof=FORID%3A10&ie=UTF-8&q=freespace&siteurl=appdb.winehq.org%2F#1030

Secondly, when you run a command in a terminal, I bet you're getting some kind of error message there when the program crashes. Most likely you need to install some library and the error message may give you some indications of which lib is missing.

Once you have some ideas what is missing, there is a program called winetricks which helps you to install stuff (mfc runtime, directx etc.) - it installs original windows libs instead of their wine re-implementations - which may make things better or worse, you don't know until you try :)

Don't be afraid to break things - all your Wine files are stored in .wine directory so if everything stop working completely you'll be able to delete this directory and wine will reset to default settings.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to fix it is to ask for help from people who know Wine well. Not many users on AskUbuntu will be able to help you, so if I were you I would go to http://www.winehq.org/help/ and request help on a Wine-related site - you are much more likely find someone competent there than here.